# Visual Studio 2012 uninstalling taking too long

Tags: visual-studio

I have an ultimate version of Visual Studio 2012 on my PC. But since it has been acting weird lately like I can't open my previous project and etc., I've decided it's better to uninstall it then install again. But,  2 days had passed, the uninstalling process still isn't done. Why is it taking too long? Is there any easier way to remove all its component so that I can have it reinstalled again? Is it a requirement to have an internet connection while uninstalling it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try boot your computer in **clean boot** mode and then try to unistall.

How to proceed with clean boot for Windows 10:

1. From Start, search for **msconfig**.
2. Select **System Configuration** from the search results.
3. On the **Services** tab of the **System Configuration** dialog box, tap or click to select the **Hide all Microsoft services** check box, and then tap or click **Disable all**.
4. On the **Startup** tab of the **System Configuration** dialog box, tap or click **Open Task Manager**.
5. On the **Startup** tab in Task Manager, for each startup item, select the item and then click **Disable**.
6. Close Task Manager
7. On the **Startup** tab of the **System Configuration** dialog box, tap or click **OK**, and then restart the computer.

Comment: Can you include a text version of the answer in your post instead of just a link? It does help to make your answer searchable should any other user experience the same problem. You can at least provide bulletpoint list of actions to take and refer to the link as a full source. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I hope it looks better now.

Comment: Thanks @mcfb, I'll try this one later. I'll update you if it works which I hope it will. :)